# GREP ; 1.Use file as input 2. Append to Every Match

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

Looking to match and append to match in linux/unix. Perhaps sed/awk

cat Data.txt

```
 RMS_QUANTITY_RT
 SMS_QUANTITY_RT
```

file.xml

```
 <!-- dec=664, SMS_QUANTITY_RT -->
 <!-- dec=664, RMS_QUANTITY_RT -->
```

PROJECTED RESULTS

```
 <!-- dec=664, SMS_QUANTITY_RT OK TO REMOVE -->
 <!-- dec=664, RMS_QUANTITY_RT OK TO REMOVE-->
```

```
grep -f Data.txt file.xml | NOT SURE how to do this part
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this all in one step using `sed` substitution.

```
sed 's/RMS_QUANTITY_RT\|SMS_QUANTITY_RT/& OK TO REMOVE/g'
```

I just took your two search terms and made them an 'OR' regex in `sed`'s substitution command. If you had a ton of strings it'd likely be easier to make the list into a list of `sed` commands and use the `-f` flag to have sed read the script from a file.

Here's how this works - in `sed`'s regex substitution, `&` is a special char that returns the matched string of the regex, so our sed is saying match either "RMS_QUANTITY_RT" or "SMS_QUANTITY_RT" and then replacing that with whatever it matched and the static string " OK TO REMOVE".

Give this sample input:

```
$ cat xml.test
<!-- dec=664, SMS_QUANTITY_RT -->
<bad tag>
value value
</bad tag>
 <!-- dec=664, RMS_QUANTITY_RT -->
<bad tag>
value value
</bad tag>
```

We see this output running the command:

```
$ sed 's/RMS_QUANTITY_RT\|SMS_QUANTITY_RT/& OK TO REMOVE/g' xml.test
<!-- dec=664, SMS_QUANTITY_RT OK TO REMOVE -->
<bad tag>
value value
</bad tag>
 <!-- dec=664, RMS_QUANTITY_RT OK TO REMOVE -->
<bad tag>
value value
</bad tag>
```

Modifying this to then read from a file and edit the XML in place, we use a simple loop to read the files lines then do a `sed -i` to do the replacement in place:

```
while read n; do sed -i "s/$n/& OK TO REMOVE/g" file.xml; done < Data.txt
```

Here you can see this working:

```
$ cat file.xml
<!-- dec=664, SMS_QUANTITY_RT -->
<bad tag>
value value
</bad tag>
 <!-- dec=664, RMS_QUANTITY_RT -->
<bad tag>
value value
</bad tag>
```

Data.txt:

```
$ cat Data.txt
RMS_QUANTITY_RT
SMS_QUANTITY_RT
```

And the content of file.xml after our code is ran:

```
$ while read n; do sed -i "s/$n/& OK TO REMOVE/g" file.xml; done < Data.txt
$ cat file.xml
<!-- dec=664, SMS_QUANTITY_RT OK TO REMOVE -->
<bad tag>
value value
</bad tag>
 <!-- dec=664, RMS_QUANTITY_RT OK TO REMOVE -->
<bad tag>
value value
</bad tag>
```

Comment: but I am using a file as input

Comment: Edited to address your exact query.

Answer (score 1):

This works with your sample input:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR {ok[$1]=1; next} 
    $(NF-1) in ok {$NF = "OK TO REMOVE " $NF} 
    1
' Data.txt file.xml
```

The first line stores the contents of Data.txt in the keys of the `ok` array.
The second line adds the text if the 2nd last field is found in the array keys.
The third line prints every line in file.xml